# Creating an Ajax.ActionLink using javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have a Todo List (an ASP.MVC UserControl) that for each row has the name of the task (that can be clicked to toggle between done/outstanding) and a delete button for removing the task - Both are created using Ajax.ActionLink to query the server.

When creating a new row I need the task text and delete button to be ActionLinks, how would I do this from the client side? Is there an Ajax.ActionLink equivalent in the Microsoft Ajax JS libraries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the code that is being generated using View Source.  All you need to do is add the same markup and add the correct click handler via javascript.  You may find it actually easier to do this with jQuery for all elements and add the jQuery code in your UserControl.  At least that way you control the code and if Microsoft decides to change the way their ActionLink works, you won't get caught short.